# How can I prevent installers adding shortcuts to my desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

I'm a bit anal retentive about keeping my desktop completely clear of icons, but many installers insist on adding (or re-adding) shortcuts to my desktop.

What, if anything, can I do to prevent this?

Comment: The most you can do really is to not click "add a desktop shortcut" during installations, however many don't give you the option... so I suppose the only way is to delete them afterwards or possibly if you made your desktop read only but that would seem like a pain to you for other uses..

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best option is to set your desktop to read only.

Take a look at this answer here:

[How to make Windows 7 desktop read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/435752/how-to-make-windows-7-desktop-read-only)

Read the accepted answer about writing a batch script. You should be able to do the same exact thing, just setting it to your desktop. If you need any help writing the script or making it start up feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

almost of applications ask you when installing their software whether you want to add shortcuts to desktop or not 
make sure you uncheck the checkbox

also look at this

[Can you block installers from making desktop shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/73736/can-you-block-installers-from-making-desktop-shortcuts)

Comment: Unfortunately many installers do not (Nvidia drivers, Adobe software being a couple of examples off the top of my head), which is the part I'm more interested in. I checked out the other question, but I'm more interested if there is something I can do with permissions to prevent ANY changes to the desktop, rather than allowing certain files on there but not shortcuts.

Comment: @KarlNicoll Would you be open to making your desktop read only?

Comment: @EricF - Absolutely if it achieves what I want!

Comment: if you remove assess for everyone and leave your user and system on your c:\users\user\desktop and right click and go to security you will be able to set what can be done from there remove access to write and youre set , you can read but no writing on desktop anymore